# An MPI program crashes after it's done printing output

Tags: c, crash, mpi

The following program (from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65185662/1329652)) appeared to be otherwise correct but was mysteriously crashing after printing the results. I've pasted the program as-is - see if you can spot the bug :)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int n = 16;
  int npow2 = 16 * 16;
  int world_size;
  int b[n][n];
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
  int m = world_size;
  int reg = npow2 / m;
  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  int fstart = rank * reg;
  int fend = fstart + reg;
  int myres[reg];
  int mystart = (int)(fstart / n);
  int myend = (int)(fend / n);
  int dim = myend - mystart;
  int a[dim][n];
  int i, j, k = 0;

  //all processes

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      b[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }
  }

  //eaach process initialize its contribution 

  int tmpi = 0;
  for (i = mystart; i < myend; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      a[tmpi][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }
    tmpi++;
  }

  int inx = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      myres[inx] = 0;
      int tmpres = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        tmpres = a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        myres[inx] = myres[inx] + tmpres;
      }
      inx++;
      if (inx >= reg) goto xlabel;

    }
  }

xlabel:

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  int * recvmatrix = NULL;
  if (rank == 0) {
    recvmatrix = malloc(sizeof(int) * npow2);
  }
  assert(world_size * reg == npow2);
  MPI_Gather(myres, reg, MPI_INT, recvmatrix, reg, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < npow2; i++) {
      printf("%d,", recvmatrix[i]);
      if (((i + 1) % n) == 0) printf("\n");
    }
  }

  MPI_FINALIZE();
  free(recvmatrix);
}
```

The following "fix", consisting of an include and two added lines, plastered around the issue, allowing the program to finish without crashing the root instance.

```
#include <unistd.h>

...

  if (rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < npow2; i++) {
      printf("%d,", recvmatrix[i]);
      if (((i + 1) % n) == 0) printf("\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);      // < added
    _exit(0);            // < added
  }
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The asker did not mention that the compiler was issuing a warning about implicit function declaration.

> It turns out that somehow the program was built with `-lmpi` *and* `-lmpi_mpifh` (or equivalent), i.e. **linked with the FORTRAN library too**. Perhaps the student was instructed to do this, or another student had "helped" them, or they figured out on their own how to "fix" the linker error - I can only speculate.
>  `MPI_FINALIZE()` triggers a C compiler warning, since it's not a part of the C API, but it will *happily link* - with the **Fortran** function, in all its uppercase glory. Of course it will then crash.
>  The following command line reproduces this nugget on Debian: `gcc -o mpi mpi.c -lmpi -lmpi_mpifh -I /usr/lib/include/openmpi; mpirun ./mpi`

Comment: it is also necessary to `return 0;` before leaving the `main` subroutine.

Comment: If that is the solution, why is it in a spoiler block?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Is that some MPI-specific requirement? Otherwise, what you say was true up to about 2 decades ago. Since C99, returning from main is optional, and if you look at the machine code, the equivalent of `return EXIT_SUCCESS` is always generated if you don't provide one. That was the case for C++ since "day one", i.e. one year earlier (C++98). C had to catch up :)

Comment: @HristoIliev Because it's fun to get a try at it first :) OTOH, It's the bug where I'm not sure whether I should be angry at someone, and if so - who?: the library designers, the gcc people who didn't make archaic syntax trigger errors decades ago by default, whoever cornered that student into linking the C program with a Fortran-specific library (worse if it was some sort of a "helpful" default setup)... This reminds me of `#include <ios> using namespace std; bool t() { return left != right; }`, and the legions of students thus taught to put open bear traps right under their feet. Disturbing.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica If the student had used a C99 compiler, it would have failed to compile since there is no prototype for `MPI_FINALIZE(...)`. FWIW, CentOS7 `gcc` is not `C99` by default.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, technically, GCC since 5.1.0 defaults to `gnu11`, which is the GNU dialect of ISO C11. Versions before 5.1.0 have `gnu90` as their default.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica, it's the first time I see someone using spoiler blocks here. Didn't even know they were a thing. But isn't SO supposed to be a Q&A website and not a quiz one?

Comment: @HristoIliev yep, and RHEL7 is still stuck in GNU 4.8.5 (and defaults to `gnu90`, which is less than `c99`)